# Displaying attribute image in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have an Angular application. A user can login to the application using their Facebook credentials. I need to be able to get that user's profile picture and display it in my app.

Right now, Angular is taking my `{{user.facebookImage}}` and sticking it at the end of the app URL- i.e. something like `www.exampleapp.com/user.facebookImage`.

I want it to just take the attribute and display it. Any suggestions?

```
<img id="userImg" ng-src={{user.facebookImage}}></img>
```

Comment: ng-src already evaluates the expression, so the {{ }} is not needed? Or is your question something else? (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)

Comment: What is the content of `user.facebookImage`? Specifically: is it a full URL (like `http://xxx.yyy/a/b/c.jpg`)? And: Are you really ommitting the quotes around the attribute or is it a typo? If yes, could you try *including* them, just in case...

Comment: @Busata That is not correct; in fact, the document states that the `ngSrc` param is "any string which can contain `{{}}` markup." Expressions do need to be interpolated when using `ngSrc`.

Comment: Oh yes, my mistake, sorry.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos, I've tried with the quotes too. This was just my latest attempt.. The attribute is a full url.

Comment: Strange... This code should work. There may be a bug in Angular. What version are you using? Is this behaviour consistent across browsers? Can you reproduce it in a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working in the end with `src="' + facebookImage + '"`.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure I see the issue - your facebook image url is something like `www.facebook.com/path/to/the/image.png`.  You can either do:

```
ng-src="//{{user.facebookImage}}"></img>
```

Or you can change `user.facebookImage` to include `http://` or `https://` in the url.

The issue is that it thinks it is a *relative* url, when in fact it is an *absolute* url.  So you need to let it know that it is not, and including the protocol (http or https), or tell it to use a relative *protocol* (the //).